# Back the calling page javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi there I want to back to a calling page 
My page's process is A->B->C and sometimes A->C, so i want to back like C->B->A or C->A by using button back

I have tried this one in each page

`window.history.back();`

but it work in this way A->B->C and back C->B->C

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use static links to previous page?

Comment: @Justinas I  want to use the static page too, but in some cases I can't. because it work like this A->B->C and sometimes A->C.

Comment: It would help if you showed us a bit more code.

Comment: My guess is that someone, somewhere, is munging with your history stack, perhaps your routing framework, which is...what? To help debug this, you could examine 'window.history.length' before doing the `back`. After going A > B > C, it should be three. After doing a `back`, it should **still** be three (you will be on the second entry). After doing another `back`, it should **still** be three (you will be on the first entry). If instead you find going back to `B` is increasing the length of the history stack to 4, then someone is doing something funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go specific numbers of pages to go back

```
window.location.history.go("page numbers here, for example -2");
```

**UPDATE**

It works for :

*a.html* as;

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
PAGE A
<a href="b.html">go to b</a>
</body>
</html>
```

*b.html* as;

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
PAGE B
<input type="button" value="go back" onclick="window.history.go(-1)">
<a href="c.html">go to c</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and *c.html* as;

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
PAGE C
<input type="button" value="go back" onclick="window.history.back();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @torazaburo In page 'C' he can use window.history.back(); to go back page 'B' and in page 'B', he can use window.location.history.go("-3"); to go back page 'A'.

Comment: That's why its 'go back 3 pages'. A-B-C, going back one page then you are in B, then 3 pages before is A.

Comment: @torazaburo i've updated, tested and saw how it works. Next time, please get involved in problem solving instead of judging people. If you want to see by yourself, you can test the code above.

Comment: @torazaburo I looked again and again but didnt see where op asked for an explaination, all i see is he asked for a solution which my code gives him.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

should do the trick.
The `-1` means go back 1 page. `-2` would be two pages back. `2` would be two pages forward.

Comment: Isn't `go(-1)` exactly the same as `back`, which the OP said didn't work? To what do you attribute the behavior reported by the OP?